# Removing an onclick event and triggering ist after my own onclick

Tags: javascript, onchange, addeventlistener

Is it possible to remove the onclick event from an element and saving it, so that i can add my own onclick and trigger the other one after mine?

Comment: please add your codes to demonstrate the issue you met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use $('yourelement').attr('onclick','').unbind('click'); and then you can save that particular element event and then you can assign your own event.

and please add your code so that I can help you further.